# How to set items in ListView with 6 fields in Android?

Tags: android

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textColor="#505050"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textColor="#202020"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/abs__ab_share_pack_holo_light" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25dip"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:src="@drawable/accepticon" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25dip"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:src="@drawable/rejecticon" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/runnimage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25dip"
                android:src="@drawable/running"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rejectedrequest"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Rejected"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linear2"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/revresetime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Just 5 Minute Ago"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="10dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is My Xml I am able to display item in ListView :

[image]

But I want to set my adapter Like this : Here is my ListView item :[image]

[image]

I have tried but am face issue to set margin layout and below one relative layout to linear layout please help me how to set item listview like this  there is 2 textview request  traveling and D has request for traveling for You

Comment: specify your requirement clearly please

Comment: i display list view item  like given image

Comment: @NarendraPal i have to create listview item like below image

Comment: See PRAKASH UBHADIYA answer. Its right for your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try it if you want any change then please tell me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:src="@drawable/abs__ab_share_pack_holo_light" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#505050"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/desc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:textColor="#202020"
                    android:textSize="14dp"  />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25dip"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:src="@drawable/accepticon" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25dip"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:src="@drawable/rejecticon" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/runnimage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25dip"
                android:src="@drawable/running"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rejectedrequest"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Rejected"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linear2"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/revresetime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Just 5 Minute Ago"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="10dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Anil you want  any change in xml?

Comment: see mY text is not visible and accept and reject button see how come its correctly http://snag.gy/0SdDm.jpg

Comment: you want textview left of button?

Comment: yes  but i want to make layOut Like face book what ever item we have we have to arrange Like facebook http://snag.gy/Lzqvu.jpg

Comment: yes like this but time also should come below  acept and rject icon below

Comment: please add that also and  give me Updated code so that i can change it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60680/discussion-between-prakash-ubhadiya-and-anil).

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60680/discussion-between-prakash-ubhadiya-and-anil

Answer (score 0):

what you need is a reltive layout as parent with 
1.checkbox at left and a 
2.linear layout vertical with textview and another linear layout(horizontal) for accept and deny button.
3. keep this linear layout torightof the checkbox

Comment: I have Update plz check i want like that

Comment: it's still the same you need to mix the layouts to create a complex one

Comment: i shown u listview item i want to display like that

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:text="tetstetetet"
                android:textColor="#505050"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/desc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="testtesttest"
                android:textColor="#202020"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/runnimage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="25dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/rejectedrequest"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dip"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Rejected"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/revresetime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Just 5 Minute Ago"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried Your Code its Looking Like this http://snag.gy/0SdDm.jpg
     
http://paste.ofcode.org/FqAWKRTfrZcVaayUgu8Jrt here is Xml Code

Comment: u there please suggest